# Как проверить что вложенный запрос возвращает NULL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть следующий запрос:

```
select * from table1 
where 
    table1_id = 26 and 
    table1_date like (select table2_date from table2 where table2_id = 30) and
    table1_type in (select table2_type from table2 where table2_id = 30);
```

`table1_type` и `table2_type` могут принимать значение `NULL`. Т.е., мне в запросе может понадобиться проверить, что значение `NULL`. Нo такой запрос ничего не возвращает (без ошибки, просто пустая строка). Значения все верные.

Что не так и можно ли поправить?

Comment: 1. `NULL` не равно `NULL`, 2. я не понял что Вам надо

Comment: 1. Альтернативы есть? Мне надо проверить, что значения table1_type и table2_type  соответствуют друг другу, какими бы они не были.
2. Можно ли в запрос 1 раз передать значение и потом как-то его вызывать или сравнивать поля группами?

Comment: Запрос написан не правильно. Третье условие `in` подразумевает много значений. Второе сравнивает с одним значением, но сами подзапросы одинаковые. Сравнение `in` может принимать несколько значений `(v1, v2) in (select...)`

Comment: Приведите структуру может вопрос станет понятнее.

Comment: Проверить, что `null` конструкция `not exists`

Comment: По поводу привести структуру не совсем понял. Может это имеете ввиду: есть 2 разные таблицы, но содержащие несколько одинаковых параметров которые должны быть равны. Например: дата в обоих таблицах в поле "date" должна быть одинаковая. По поводу not exist повторюсь: поле может быть NULL в обоих таблицах, а может быть 5. Мне надо убедиться, что значение поля одинаковое. Без разницы какое (null, 5, 1, 33), но одинаковое. Это ключевой момент, который я не могу решить.

Comment: _По поводу привести структуру не совсем понял_, дополните [здесь](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6e293e342e870ea04541fcd841fc81eb) данными, опубликуйте обновлённый линк, и поясните, что не получается.

Comment: [Вот](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6e293e342e870ea04541fcd841fc81eb), @0xdb , 
 запрос по равенству значений (в данном  случае null) который ничего не  выводит. Убрал все лишние пол для простоты.

Comment: Поправте ссылку, вы опубликовали мою же, которую я дал парой комментариев выше.

Comment: Извеняюсь, [поправил](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1700b48b6f9e72bb81073ce552da2be2)

Comment: Рад был помочь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На основе [данных](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1700b48b6f9e72bb81073ce552da2be2), предоставленных ТС, предложу сделать так (на [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=54ebf2a8fb068574cb379ab69b73e15d)):

```
select * from table1 
where table1_id = 30 
and exists (select 1
    from table2 
    where table2_id = 26
    and (table2_type = table1_type or (table2_type is null and table1_type is null))
    and (table2_date = table1_date or (table2_date is null and table1_date is null)))
```

Если есть возможность задать значения, которые гарантированно не могут встретится в реальных данных, то в подзапросе можно использовать такое условие:

```
where table2_id = 26
and coalesce (table2_type, 'undef') = coalesce (table1_type, 'undef')
and coalesce (table2_date, date'0001-01-01') = coalesce (table1_date, date'0001-01-01')
```

Но такое условие не будет ни производительней, ни более читабельным.

Comment: ` and table2_type = table1_type or (table2_type is null and table1_type is null)` - всё заработало, спасибо!

Comment: Единственное взял в скобки всё после каждого `and`. [Вот](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4f44dff80d1f50bcd5040d810dfa1a8b)

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select 
  t1.* 
from table1 t1
where t1.table1_id = 26 
and ((t1.table1_date, t1.table1_type) in (
  select 
    t2.table2_type, t2.table2_date 
  from table2 t2
  where table2_id = 30) or exists (
    select 
      null
    from table2 t22
    where t22.table2_id = 30
    and    t22.table1_date is null
    and    t22.table1_type is null
    and    t1.table1_date is null
    and    t1.table1_type is null));
```

Comment: Спасибо, значит через "ИЛИ" делать. Понял.

Comment: t22.table1_date, спасибо за такую конструкцию, ушёл от многократной передачи значения поля в запросе. С `null` как в ответе выше.